# What is jHipster way to migrate the same jHipster project from monolith to microservices project?

Tags: java, jhipster

So, how to regenerate the microservice project for exactly the same in terms of UI and data model that was previously generated as monolith?

It is guided no to use microservices until the monolith works for you. With jHipter it is easy to start both from scratch. If I develop so much for the monolith jHipster projects (here I mean not only the code generation, but writing own code based on the generated one), is there a way to re-generate the project as microservices, at least having the generated for monolith code being regenerated with the same data model with no need to copy paste it form the initial project. And even better - with all code changes done for the jHipster monolith code saved.

Comment: Hi Ilya, were you able to find any guidance or recommendations?

Comment: @juanmgar, no, and for now the question is't so actual for me. I think you can raise this question in JHipster Gitter https://gitter.im/jhipster/home

Comment: @Gaël Marziou have you any recommendations for that?